# Find specific text or dates inside a range and mark line with a specific colour

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have report were I use a VBA Macro to get a list from a large amount of Raw Data.
I have a very specific need, I  hope someone can help me with.

My range is from A5:I500, each line from A:I has information to a specific need.

If a cell in the "H" Column has a specific text (in my case "Unconfirmed"), I would like The entire line (for instance A5:I5 or A26:I26), to be marked in a specific color.

If "H" Column has a date which is later than the date of "today", I would like the line (for instance A5:I5 or A26:I26), to be marked in a specific color.

If "H" Column has a date which is before the date of "today", I would like the line (for instance A5:I5 or A26:I26), to be marked in a specific color.

[I want to end up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAWg8.png)

I found code which turns just the specific cell in the color I want.
How do I change this code to fill the entire Line from A:I on every line which contains "unconfirmed"?

```
Sub test1() 

Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MySearch As Variant
Dim myColor As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim I As Long

MySearch = Array("Unconfirmed")
myColor = Array("3")

With Sheets("Ronnie").Range("A5:I1000")
For I = LBound(MySearch) To UBound(MySearch)

Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = myColor(I)
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    Next I
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could do this with conditional formatting, unless there is a reason for it to be scripted. Also provide a screenshot with the conditions and the results required. Also do you have any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi, no I need to have this in VBA. I do this report several times, and have one Macro to do numerous things. So this is to save time.

I have searched and tried to find code that works for me, but have not found any thing that seems to fit.

Comment: I have added a picture of how I want it to end up.

Comment: I have also added new code I found which manages to tur every cell with a specific value to the color I want. But I need the entire line to change color (From A:I)

Answer (score 0):

This code will use if statements to check the data, and assign colour to the range of cells on that row.

```
Sub ColourRng()

Dim RNum As Integer

RNum = 1

For I = 1 To 500

If Sheets("Ronnie").Range("H" & RNum) = "Unconfirmed" Then
    Sheets("Ronnie").Range("A" & RNum & ":I" & RNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    Else
    
    If Sheets("Ronnie").Range("H" & RNum) >= Date Then
        Sheets("Ronnie").Range("A" & RNum & ":I" & RNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    
        Else
    
        If Sheets("Ronnie").Range("H" & RNum) < Date Then
            Sheets("Ronnie").Range("A" & RNum & ":I" & RNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        
    End If
   
End If
RNum = RNum + 1
    
Next I

End Sub
```